A first order differential equation: Inconsistent solutions by two approaches
Assuming $a>0,b>0,c>0$, in matrix A = {{a - I*b, c}, {c, a + I*b}};  I am interested in solving the following differential equation $\frac{d}{dt}R(t) = -i(A R(t) - R(t) A^\dagger)$, where $A^\dagger$ is the conjugate-transpose of $A$. Here is my code
ini = R[0] == {{s00, s01}, {s10, s11}};
R[t_] = {{r00[t], r01[t]}, {r10[t], r11[t]}};   
 solR = DSolve[{D[R[t], t] == (-I)*(A . R[t] - R[t] . ConjugateTranspose[A]), ini}, Flatten[R[t]], t]

Unfortunately, this yields {{r00[t] -> ComplexInfinity,  r01[t] -> ComplexInfinity,  r10[t] -> ComplexInfinity,  r11[t] -> ComplexInfinity}}.
By direct approach: noting that $\frac{d}{dt}R(t) = -i(A R(t) - R(t) A^\dagger)$ has the solution $R(t) = e^{-i A t} R(0) e^{i A^\dagger t}$, the following code does not lead to ComplexInfinity solution
    R0 = {{s00, s01}, {s10, s11}}; 
   SolR=MatrixExp[(-I)*A*t] . Rinitial . MatrixExp[I*ConjugateTranspose[A]*t]

I want to understand what is "wrong" with the first approach?

I'm using V 13.3. What result do you obtain?

In both Wolfram Language 13.3.0 Engine for Linux and the cloud version 14.0.0, the original code produces the error message "DSolve::nolist: List encountered within ... There should be no lists on either side of the equations."  The DEs and ICs can be rewritten using Flatten and Thread to eliminate the disallowed lists, as
ClearAll["Global`*"]
r[t_]= {{r00[t], r01[t]}, {r10[t], r11[t]}};
ini= {{s00, s01}, {s10, s11}};
amat={{a-I*b, c}, {c, a+I*b}};
adgr=ConjugateTranspose[amat] //ComplexExpand;

(  ics = Thread[Flatten[ r[0]] == Flatten[ini]]  )//ColumnForm
(  odes = Thread[D[Flatten[r[t]],t] == -I*Flatten[amat.r[t]-r[t].adgr]]  )//ColumnForm
solR1 = DSolveValue[Flatten@{odes,ics}, Flatten[r[t]], t]//Simplify;

The solution is a bit too complicated.  Making the substitution $b^2 \rightarrow c^2-\omega^2/4$ and multiplying the solution by $\omega^3$ allows some simplification, as
solR2 = ω^3 solR1 /.b^2->c^2+ω^2/4 //PowerExpand //ExpToTrig //FullSimplify;
solR2 //ColumnForm 


You may want to make different substitutions or not use ComplexExpand depending on the values of your constants.
The DSolveValue solution can be compared to the MatExp form as follows.
altSol1 = MatrixExp[(-I)*amat*t] . ini . MatrixExp[I*adgr*t];
altSol2 = ω^3 altSol1  /.b^2->c^2+ω^2/4 //PowerExpand //ComplexExpand //ExpToTrig //Simplify;
(  Flatten[altSol2] == solR2 //Thread  ) /.b->Sqrt[c^2+ω^2/4] //Simplify

{True,True,True,True} 

Note this approach uses PowerExpand and ComplexExpand. Each of them makes assumptions about expressions being positive and real.  Use ArrayReshape to transform solR1 and solR2 back to 2x2 nested lists.
